# [angular][single-spa] different build result by differen OS

Tags: angular, single-spa

I have an Anglular application that is using the single-spa-angular framework: https://single-spa.js.org/

By doing the same build on two different environments I have two different dist contents.
locally we are on a windows environment.
in a jenkins pipe we are on a linux environment.

the result on ambien windows works if integrated with the other single-spa modules. the result from ambiene linux doesn't work.

the difference is evident in the number of chunks generated (one more in the linux version that doesn't work)

do you have any idea why this difference and how to solve the problem?

Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: This seems more like an Angular cli problem than a single-spa problem...

Comment: @filoxo Why it should be a problem related to angular-cli rather than single-spa? Can you give me more info please?

Comment: Because single-spa makes only minimal changes to the config just to setup the parts that are required for microfrontends (just module format, and publicPath type stuff) but it does not do any conditional logic for environment configs. In other words, the changes the single-spa-angular generator are not target- or browser-specific.